# How can I read .txt file from GoogleDrive in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-drive-api

I want to use .txt file located on my GoogleDrive as a repository for some values. I need to read that file and put the values from inside into an ArrayList (or some kind of list).

I have tried using AsyncTask and URL classes but all get from reading this URL was some html code.

So, does anybody know how to get values from .txt file on GoogleDrive? Thank you!

Comment: It might help if you show what you have tried, and what the output was vs what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Disregard what I said earlier, I misread the question.

[This](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples) this might be what you want to look into.